# No response from any of the 3 replicas

Tags: cassandra, timeout, replication, consistency

I need help understanding why a query with ConsistencyLevel.ONE would receive no response from any of the 3 replicas (RF=3).  This happens sporadically, but frequently enough to cause headaches.

I see the same thing occasionally when doing queries with QUORUM, which I could *almost* rationalize as something like 2/3 of the replicas are "down" doing compaction, GC, *something*.

But with ONE, doesn't that mean all 3 replicas are "down"?  What could cause them to be down?  Could something else be going on?

Full disclosure: we're running 2.1.9 with 15 nodes in a single data center in GCE, but the nodes are in 3 different zones.  As far as I know, this isn't due to a network partition among the zones, but anything is possible.

Please help me understand the possible causes for 0 replicas responding.  Thanks in advance!

Here's an example of an exception:

cassandra.OperationTimedOut: errors={: ReadTimeout('Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes\' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={\'received_responses\': 0, \'required_responses\': 1, \'consistency\': \'ONE\'}',), : ConnectionException('Host has been marked down or removed',)}, last_host=10.240.0.31

Comment: What load balancing policy are you using?

Comment: in the output of "nodetool tpstats" do you see any non-zero values in "Dropped" messages or "All time blocked" ?

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson in the case of the error above, we're not explicitly setting the load balancing policy, so I _believe_ it's RoundRobinPolicy.  I'm almost positive we've seen this same issue when using TokenAwarePolicy in other services.

Comment: @JKVS yes, running "nodetool tpstats" on all 15 nodes, I see a wide variety of "Dropped" messages (none blocked).  Is that a clue?  I'll be Googling for that...

Comment: In that case it could be that you're overloading your system.

Comment: What Message types are dropped and how many?
Dropped messages could be overloading like Simon says. Look at the system.log around the timestamp of the errors for any long GC pauses (> 1sec).
They will look something like "G1 Young Generation GC in XXXms."

Comment: @JKVS here are tpstats from all 15 nodes, dropped messages of various types, and different orders of magnitude quantities from node to node (which I assume may be a factor of how long each node has been up).   https://gist.github.com/dcheckoway/044c533b11aa2a1d6ca1183baac5ef98    I really appreciate the time you guys are taking to help me.  Any advice on how to interpret this is much appreciated!

Comment: Oh...worth noting is that we're using G1GC, which I believe has eliminated the long GC pauses.  I'll reconfirm that we're not seeing any surprises there.

Comment: FWIW, we're pretty consistently seeing on the order of 200-300ms GC pauses.  i.e. "G1 Young Generation GC in 280ms".  Occasionally an outlier in the ~400ms range, but I haven't seen anything > 1sec.

Comment: I didn't spot anything obvious from those tpstats.. 
If you have any cluster monitoring I'd be looking for any signs of overloading CPU, Disk IO, Read latency and Network.